# The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'app-guid' named 'app-name'. Send an interactive authorization

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

**My setup**

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app configured with Azure AD. I have an ASP.NET Core Web API configured Azure AD.

I obtain the token in the client web app and use it when requesting resources from the Web API, this works fine. I get responses and I can obtain the current user making the request. I used this MS guide [active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg)

I want to enable communication between the Web API and Microsoft Graph. I have followed part of this Azure sample [Web API now calls Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph)

**The issue**

I have had issues accessing the MS Graph API from my ASP.NET Core API. I have set up everything I think should be as seen in the code and screenshot below, however, I keep getting the error.

> InnerException = {"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'app-guid' named 'app-name. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource
>
> Message = IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.

I have granted admin consent in the API permissions section, the app uses delegated permissions, it is an organisational app, users must be on Azure AD to login.

**API StartUp File**

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

**API App Settings**

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "removed",
    "TenantId": "removed",
    "ClientId": "removed"
},
"DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read presence.read mailboxsettings.read mail.read calendars.read files.readwrite"
},
```

**Permissions for the Web.API on Azure**

[API Permissions on azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKk59.png)

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[RequiredScope("scope.name")]
[ApiController]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; private set; }

    public ExampleController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DealDto>>> GetDealsWithAccount()
    {
        try
        {
            User user = _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Additional thing I have done**

On Microsoft Azure, the expose an API section, I have also copied the api://application-guid/scope.name to my API app settings scope. I can the same error message.

Comment: I have to inform you that when we want to generate access token from azure ad, we can only set one kind of api scope in the request, that means we can't generate an access token which has graph api permission and your custom api permission at the same time.

Comment: Then let's go back to your issue, your scenario is that you need to access your asp.net core api via your custom api permission and your api need to call ms graph api, so you should use onbehalf flow here. I recommend you following  this sample:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph

Comment: Hi @TinyWang, I just read through the link and checked the code and azure. I edited my controller to include the itokenAcquistion I have added client Id as part of knownClientApplications and confirmed it. There no change same error. I have tried this link earlier.

Comment: This is where the doc speaks about binding the permissions. =>  However, since the middle tier cannot interact with the signed-in user, it needs to be explicitly bound to the client app in its Azure AD registration. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph#configure-known-client-applications-for-service-todolistservicems-identity-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2

Answer (score 1):

The error usually occurs if you have missed granting admin consent for the required permissions.

Please **note** that, after exposing the API make sure to grant API permissions for the same.

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> My APIs -> Your API*

[image]

Make sure to grant the admin consent for the API permission.

If the issue persists, try setting the below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings*

[image]

For more in detail, please refer to these links:

[Fixed – AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID by Nishant Rana's Weblog](https://nishantrana.me/2020/12/01/fixed-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application-with-id/)

[Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent)

Comment: Hi @rukmimiMr-MT thank you for your response. 

I have granted admin access again to all these permissions user.read presence.read mailboxsettings.read mail.read calendars.read files.readwrite profile offline_access openid in both ways as specified above. The user content settings is also identical to the picture you have above. I have also granted tenant wide access like specified in the links, however, I am still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Interested to know if you got this working as I have the exact same issue. Thanks